# Error when pressing the Enter key, C# console

Tags: c#, error-handling, key, enter

My code asks the user to enter a letter (convert `string` to `char`), but when pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key as an input the code crashes.

I failed to put any conditions to send an error message to the user to not press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key at the input and enter only letters.

Here is the part I'm struggling with :

```
public static char GetLetter(string prompt)
{
    char result;

    Console.Write("\n\t" + prompt + ":  ");
    result = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

    if(result == '!' || result == '@' || result == '#'  || result == '$' || result == '%'  )
    // we can keep going with all the unwanted characters and numbers 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\t NO MATCH ! \n\t ,please try again using letters only , ");
        result = GetLetter(prompt);
        return result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: We're going to need to see the actual error and the input.

Comment: Console.ReadKey could do it, no?

Comment: @AlexandreTryHardLeblanc, exactly where I was heading; and it's the more correct approach, but I'm still a bit curious about the actual error and input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting an error when you enter because you get an empty string, so you can't convert it to char.

I would offer you to do that:

```
char result;
string input = Console.ReadLine();

if (char.TryParse(input, out result))
{
    //The input is a char - write your code here.
}

//The input is not a char.
```

Comment: Do you know a better way to have the user entering letters only ?Cause I think my code looks wiered with all the || ORs :/

Comment: You can use the IsLetter method, like this: `if (char.IsLetter(result))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Console.ReadKey()` function to read the character as below:

```
public static char GetLetter(string prompt)
{
    char result;

    Console.Write("\n\t" + prompt + ":  ");
    result = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

    if (result == '!' || result == '@' || result == '#' || result == '$' || result == '%')
    // we can keep going with all the unwanted characters and numbers 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\t NO MATCH ! \n\t ,please try again using letters only , ");
        result = GetLetter(prompt);
        return result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ah it gave me the result once I pressed any letter key that I didn't need to prees the Enter key .That is a good one too,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Console.ReadLine()` will return a `string`, not a `char`, use `Console.Read` instead. Check the [details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from MSDN